# Converting portable, imperative code to reactive without resorting to blocking?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have some legacy imperative code for saving & loading objects by key in multiple document datastores. Essentially, it's written portably so the DatastoreClient knows nothing about the data it's storing, but is given a key by the repository using it for predictable retrieval. What would be the best way to make that pattern reactive?

Legacy code is of the form

```java
public class CustomerRepository implements CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    private final DatastoreClient datastoreClient;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); //jackson.fasterxml

    public CustomerRepository(final DatastoreClient datastoreClient) {
        this.datastoreClient = datastoreClient;
    }

    public void createOrUpdate(Customer c) {
        datatoreClient.makeAndStoreDocument(mapper.convertValue(c, Map.class), 
                                            c.getId());
    }
}
```

I've managed to rewrite `datatoreClient.createOrUpdate(...)` to use the Project Reactor types `Mono<Map<String,Object>>` and `Mono<Long|String>`, but what is the right way to get the object and key to this method reactively? Or is the better answer to start from scratch on the interfaces?

```java
public Mono<Void> createOrUpdateReactive(final Mono<Customer> customerMono) {
    return customerMono.flatMap(customer -> datastoreClient
                                              .makeAndStoreDocument(
                                                 Mono.just(mapper.convertValue(customer, Map.class)), 
                                                 Mono.just(customer.getId())
                                              )
                                );
}
```

Doesn't this end up blocking to unpack the real data out of the first Mono?

I added underlying DatastoreClient makeAndStoreDocument function

```java
public class GoogleFirestoreClient implements DatastoreClient {
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> makeAndStoreDocument(final Mono<Map<String, Object>> model, final Mono<String> key) {
        //The client library for Firestore is synchronous/blocking, so we offload the actual request to a separate, elastic thread pool.
        //When the result comes back, a separate, asynchronously generated result goes back up the chain.
        return Mono.zip(model, key)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnNext(tuple -> db.collection(collectionName).document(tuple.getT2()).set(tuple.getT1()))
                .retryWhen(Retry.max(3).filter(error -> error instanceof InterruptedException))
                .doOnSuccess(tuple -> System.out.println("Wrote object: " + tuple.getT1() + " to Firestore collection " + collectionName))
                .doOnError(ExecutionException.class, ee -> logger.error("ExecutionException in createOrUpdateReactive. ", ee))
                .doOnError(InterruptedException.class, ie -> logger.error("Reactive CreateOrUpdate interrupted more than limit allows.", ie))
                .then();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, why two Monos? You could use a Mono with a Tuple for both values or a representative class with a Map and Id as properties. I would not favor the approach of having one function operate on two separate Monos.

Comment: not related to the question, but why would you (or the legacy application) not use the CrudRepository standard  `save` method and instead implement POST/PUT/PATCH calls in a way that there is no response? REST APIs should always return the created/ updated resource in the response.

Comment: What is `makeAndStoreDocument`?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Bearing in mind I'm new to the Reactor libraries and style, but with the edit including the implementation of the datastoreClient, is there a better way you see to do this? Historically, we mint an Entity somewhere higher up the stack, it comes down, we extract a key to be used for whatever doc store we're using today (Couch, Mongo, HBase, and Firestore), and we store it with that key as the label. Can you provide an example of converting a Mono<some_type> to a Mono<Tuple2>? Or would that have needed to be done from the inception of the Mono? That seems to break encapsulation...

Comment: @Toerktumlare Added.

Comment: When you don't have the luxury of experience, and everyone wants an interface that's as close to what they're used to as possible, you ask questions that experienced people think are trivial. If the answer is "there's not really a good way," you can say so, a bit more respectfully perhaps...

Comment: @patrickjp93 being respectful is not asaking questions that take up others time. A lot of us spend time here to help people with complicated problems, as a last resort. If you are just looking for a code review, it would be respectful of you to actually google and see that these questions are suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ voted to close

Comment: @Toerktumlare I'm not sure this would work well on CR either. CR likes a bit more context with their code, while this seems slimmed down in SO style.

Comment: The DatastoreClient is never meant to know a thing about the type of data it's storing. It's just a thin wrapper around the native client libraries for Couch, Mongo, etc.. For whatever reason, my predecessors chose to pass down Map<K,V> and some pre-determined key known by the Repository to make it portable. Is there a good way to take that portable, imperative pattern and make it Reactive?

Comment: @patrickjp93 dont ask new questions in comments. Update your original question if you feel the need to clarify your question.

Comment: @patrickjp93 its in the manual, last line in the `full example` which could be found by just searching the manual for `tuple` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.8/reference/index.html#_full_example or google searching for the tuples in reactor api https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/util/function/Tuples.html and then understanding that `map` on a `Mono<T>` maps one type `T` to another type for instance `Mono<Tuple<T1, T2>>` as the name `map` suggests.

Answer (score 1):

> but what is the right way to "split" my Mono in the caller?

There is no *right answer*, you design your API the way you want. As long as you don't call `block` or in this specific case call `subscribe` then you can solve this however works best for you in accordance to your teams decision in designing the API to the database.

How to design API's are out of scope for this question, and is extremely opinion based. What I can suggest in this case is looking into the [single responsibility principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) which means one things does one thing and it does it really good.

`makeAndStoreDocument` does two things (hence the name), which is not inherently wrong, but can for instance be harder to test, since you need to test for two things in one single thing (what if you need to change one thing but not the other, then tests need to be rewritten and can build up complexity).

But now we are in opinion based territory and Stack Overflow is not the site for such discussions, there are better sites for that purpose.

[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

[Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)